# What is wrong with this CSS code?

Tags: html, css

Why does this code not give me two columns? I have looked at it for too long for my brain to work. I am then using media queries to change it from two columns to one.

```
body {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

section {
    width: 70%;  // 70 percent of its container
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    padding:30px;
}

p {
    webkit-columns:2;
    columns:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:20px;
    -moz-column-gap:20px;
    column-gap:20px;
}

img {
    width:100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    p{
        -webkit-columns:1;
        -moz-columns:1;
        columns:1;
    }
}
```

Comment: We'll probably want to see your HTML code, too. And bear in mind that a double slash '//' isn't a valid comment delimiter in CSS, from what I remember...

Comment: You are missing a - in front of webkit-columns.

Comment: Give us you html code or a fiddle to play with... also that `css` has too many errors to be valid.

Comment: it works now it was the -

Comment: Dont sweat it inspired, I once left the  . off of $.ajax and looked for 3 days for the problem

Answer (score 4):

add the dash before `webkit`?

```
-webkit-columns:2;
-moz-columns:2; /* for firefox */
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your site through this: http://prefixr.com/
Follow the directions listed on the site.
This should be the quickest fix to your problem.

Comment: I a actually following a tutorial on nettuts from the creator on prefixr.com. I have run my code through it, I just deleted the - by accident, it works now.

Comment: You can also use prefixfree.js as well

Comment: Always awesome to hear that your code works. If you use sublime text they have a plugin for adding browser prefixes to code look on the site of prefixer. Visual Studios 2012+ has that built right in. Try using a much more modern editor, that knows what html5 and css3 is, while your coding to avoid this problem in the future. Happy Coding!

Comment: I actually tried doing that when following his tutorial but the API link is dead, it does not work.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Another rule of thumb I follow is, **If this is a personal project**: Develop for a specific browser first (I.E. Chrome) and this way I know that my css isn’t wrong I just need to add on the CSS browser vendor prefixes (these is the generic name for browser specific prefixes, which we have been using in our conversation ;)). Awesome nice to hear for a new developer. Keep up the good work, programming is awesome!! You can always tweet me [@muhammadkhan_40](https://twitter.com/muhammad_khan40)